# Keras Conv2D output dimension. Multiclass instance segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, object-detection

Im trying to create a keras instance segmentation CNN model with an Unet architecture. 
The Keras CNN model i want to use/modify is:[model.py](https://ufile.io/32zp4)
The CNN model should be able to detect 3 different object classes:(Main root, secondary root, stem).

I've converted the annotation-polygons(3 classes) to bitmap masks with a modified version of the balloon.py file in the samples folder in:[GitHub: Mask RCNN Instance segmentation package](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN)

My annotation->bitmap mask file:[annotation.py](https://ufile.io/65k2x)
Visualization of bitmaps of the 3 classes:
[image: Bitmap masks]

I want a last Conv2D output of 3 (my classes) feature maps, a final softmax activation and an categorical_crossentropy. I don't know how to "compare" my annotations to the models predictions. Do i have to use some kind of keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) function after the last Conv2D layer(conv9) in my [model.py](https://ufile.io/32zp4) file?

Comment: If you are using `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function and `softmax` as the activation of last layer then I think there would be no need for any other thing.

Comment: Where do i insert the bitmap masks of the 3 categories?

Comment: They are the labels, right? So you need to pass them as `y` to `fit` method.